# Jupyter lab delete all default shortcuts

Tags: jupyter-lab

I would like to delete the existing keybindings used in JupyterLab and only have the ones I set myself. The most obvious solution would be to go into settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> System Defaults (left pane) and just delete the list there, but the field is not possible to edit.

I have found that I can define a shortcuts in `User Preferences`, but it's long end tedious as I have to edit every single shortcut, like the example below. **Is there a** smarter **way**, something that would disable all default bindings and leave my own shortcuts or is disabling them one by one in a json?

```
{ 
"shortcuts":
[ 
    {
    "command": "notebook:delete-cell",
    "keys": [
        "D",
        "D"
    ],
    "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
    "disabled": true
    }
    ]
}
```

EDIT 01:
**I want to especially remove the dreaded ctrl+d key binding which is not listed in the list at all**

EDIT 02:
UPdate - It appears this is not possible to blanket disable all commands so they have to be removed manually by overriding with something. Would be nice to have an option to just kill the shortcut, but my current workaround looks like this:

```
{ 
"shortcuts":
[ 
    {
        "command": "notebook:delete-cell",
        "keys": [
            "D",
            "D"
        ],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
        "disabled": true
    },
    {
        "command": "notebook:clear-cell-output",
        "keys": [
            "Ctrl D"
        ],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook",
        "disabled": false
    },
    {
        "command": "notebook:run-cell",
        "keys": [
            "Ctrl R"
        ],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook",
        "disabled": false
    }
]
}
```

effectively replaced it with cell output clear

Comment: `Ctrl` + `d` comes from CodeMirror, your best luck would be to define another shortcut for it to some harmless command to overwrite it.